# Hibernating vs Shutdown/ Restart - which is better if suspend is not an option for SSD equipped systems?

Tags: touchpad, suspend, ssd

Basic gist is: my laptop is like many others that have the touchpad dead issue after resuming a suspended session. Also like others, the touchpad is working after resuming from a hibernate as well as simply restarting.

Basically it appears no final single solution is forthcoming especially seeing past posts on this matter across various hardware and software changes the past 4 years.

However I'd like to take into consideration to be gentle as much as possible to my SSD.

So with that - is it better to implement hibernation (with either a swap file or partition) or just go thru a normal restart / shutdown procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use hibernation on SSD. It is very "gentle", because you do it just a few times a day. It is much less writes that a working system is doing.

Resume from hibernation is fast and it is the best solution from all points of view.